# Iframe resize not working during second load in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe, resize, onload

IFrame is designed to be resized according to its content and it works on most browser but only in **Mozilla Firefox**, ONLY the first load is working but loading event afterwards is not working.

To let it works again, need to *refresh the page* or either *clear the cache of the browser* first..

The code is as below:

```
function sizeIFrame() {
var subscriptionFrame = jQuery("#subscriptionFrame");
var innerDoc = (subscriptionFrame.get(0).contentDocument) ?subscriptionFrame.get(0).contentDocument : subscriptionFrame.get(0).contentWindow.document;
subscriptionFrame.height(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight);   }

<iframe id="subscriptionFrame" onload="sizeIFrame();"></iframe>
```

Anyone have idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! Solution as below:

```
function sizeIFrame() {
    var subscriptionFrame = jQuery("#subscriptionFrame");
    var innerDoc = (subscriptionFrame.get(0).contentDocument) ? subscriptionFrame.get(0).contentDocument : subscriptionFrame.get(0).contentWindow.document;
    if(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight==0)
        innerDoc.location.reload(true);
    subscriptionFrame.height(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight);   
}
```

This is because Firefox load the iframe content from the cache instead of the server. So xxx.location.reload(true) will force the iframe content to load from cache. Hopes it helps u guys! =)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a DOM race condition, since it sounds like it works when the page takes longer to load (no cache) and doesn't once the cache is populated.

Try using jQuery's `load` or event instead on the `onload` attribute. jQuery handles special cases behind the scenes, so it might help.

```
<iframe id="subscriptionFrame" onload="sizeIFrame();"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#subscriptionFrame').load(function()
{
    var subscriptionFrame = this;
    var innerDoc = (this.contentDocument) ? this.contentDocument : this.contentWindow.document;
    $(this).height(innerDoc.body.scrollHeight);    
});
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with DOM race condition. Is it kind of javascript limitation or caused by the bad practice of writing javascript code?

I have tried this out but it is not really working. =(

Comment: It's really neither. It's just code that (unknowingly) depends on timing of network operations to succeed correctly. But if you say the suggest code isn't working either, it might simply be a bug in Firefox.

Comment: Yup there are some issues regards the iframe caching problem in Firefox but some of them are declared as 'FIXED'. Still, I can't find the solution for my case. Anyhow, thanks for sharing your idea.

Comment: One more thing is, even the iframe object cannot be found after the second load.